# After using the InternetConnect() API in wininet how can I tell if I'm still connected?

Tags: c#, ftp, wininet

I use the InternetConnect() method from the WinINet APIs.  I connect to my FTP server just fine with no issues.  After I connect, I wait about 1 min and the server disconnects me because of no activity as expected.  I then try to send a file but I'm not connected.

Is there a way to "check" the FTP connection to see if I'm still connected?  Or is there some type of way for me to attach an event to tell me when I get disconnected?

Comment: Write your own method to check the FTP connection:

i.e. `if (!FTPConnection) { throw new Exception("Exception Text") }`

Comment: Wow that's vague.  What type of object is FTPConnection?  Where do you get it from?

Comment: @jdweng I knew someone would suggest that.  :)  I was just using a simple example to achieve the same end results.  What happens when someone unplugs the cable, or the internet connection goes out?  What if the server admin forces the disconnection?  Either way, KeepAlive is not a valid solution.

Comment: Getting status isn't going to work either.  Disconnecting the cable the client is still going to report the connection is closed, nor will report if internet goes down.  Using ping will give more confidence, bu never complete confidence.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used wininet for FTP, and I use the classes, not the global functions directly. But I suspect that  CFtpConnection behaves the same way as  CHttpConnection in this respect. Anyway, you might learn something from what I have discovered about the latter.

CHttpConnection seems to be a high and abstract level of connection. When I started out I expected its member functions to throw exceptions once the server closed the underlying socket (for timeout). I now know better or at least believe otherwise. NORMAL closing of the socket does NOT cause exceptions to be thrown at this high level of classy wininet. You might suspect as much from inspecting the wininet error codes: There is no code corresponding to the server having closed the connection.

I experimented with this and found: The server closing the socket (for timeout) is considered normal and does not cause an exception to be thrown. You can go ahead and use CHttpConnection without worrying about this. It will simply reconnect if needed without alerting you. So once you have called GetHttpConnection and got your CHttpConnection object, it will normally last forever!

The exceptions that might be thrown, ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_ABORTED and ERROR_INTERNET_CONNECTION_RESET, are caused by abnormal conditions, f.ex. a proxy server crashing or somebody accidentally pulling the power plug to your modem. The server closing the socket for timeout is considered NORMAL and is transparent to the user of wininet classes.

So the tentative conclusion is that you don't have to worry about the connection being closed by the server. If that happens, CHttpConnection will reconnect backstage and you won't be bothered. You can pretend that the connection always stays open - it seems so to the user of wininet classes.

Consider the following experiment. A connection is opened and then a request is sent once a minute. The function returns once an exception is thrown. But if not, then it loops forever. I tried it on two different web sites: An exception is NEVER thrown! Despite a whole minute of inactivity between requests.

```
int httpclient::test(string host)
{
    int flags = INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD;
    int port = INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
    CHttpConnection *connection = session.GetHttpConnection(host.cstring(),flags,port);
    int secs = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        CHttpFile *fil;
        try 
        {
            fil = connection->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_HEAD, "index.htm",
                                            0,1,0, "HTTP/1.1", flags);
        }
        catch (CInternetException *exc)
        {
            connection->Close();
            int feil = exc->m_dwError;
            exc->Delete();
            return -feil;
        }       
        fil->AddRequestHeaders("Connection: Keep-Alive");
        try
        {
            fil->SendRequest();
        }
        catch (CInternetException *exc)
        {
            connection->Close();
            int feil = exc->m_dwError;
            exc->Delete();
            return feil;
        }       
        fil->Close();
        Sleep(60 * 1000);
        secs += 60;
        printf("%u seconds passed\n", secs);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Take all this with a grain of salt. wininet is poorly documented and all I know is what experiments have taught me.